# Swift: RegEx not returning expected results

Tags: swift, regex

Let me preface this with I am pretty noob at doing regex. The code I am writing is for macOS, not iOS but I don't think that matters in this case. I'm trying to search a git diff return based on the change range indicators. Here's is the content I am searching (the variable is called element):

```
3b8d5178f4d21e9269547e8f0bae4b7daa7d8206
Author: Steve <xxxxxx@xxxxxxx.com>
Date:   Fri Oct 4 16:55:50 2019 -0400

    Fixed responsiveness of code blocks

diff --git a/examples/video/outstream/pb-ve-outstream-no-server.html b/examples/video/outstream/pb-ve-outstream-no-server.html
index ae813578..e18e31ec 100644
--- a/examples/video/outstream/pb-ve-outstream-no-server.html
+++ b/examples/video/outstream/pb-ve-outstream-no-server.html
@@ -24,7 +24,7 @@ sidebarType: 4

        <div>

-           <div>
+           <div style="width:60vw;">

                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit ....</p>
            </div>
@@ -33,7 +33,7 @@ sidebarType: 4
                <p>Prebid Outstream Video Ad</p>
             </div>

-           <div>
+           <div style="width:60vw;">
                <p>Sed ut perspiciatis ...</p>
             </div>
        </div>          
@@ -49,9 +49,9 @@ sidebarType: 4
            Do not forget to exchange the placementId in the code examples with your own placementId!</p>
        </div>

-       <div>
+       <div style="width:60vw;">
            <h4>Place this code in the page header.</h4>
-<pre class="pb-code-hl">
+<pre class="pb-code-hl" style="width:60vw;">
 <!--put javascript code here-->
 &lt;script&gt;
     var pbjs = pbjs || {};
@@ -95,9 +95,9 @@ sidebarType: 4
        </div>

        <!--body code example-->
-       <div>
+       <div style="width:60vw;">
            <h4>Place this code in the page body.</h4>
-<pre class="pb-code-hl">
+<pre class="pb-code-hl" style="width:60vw;">
 <!--put body html and javascript here-->
 &lt;div id='video1'&gt;
    &lt;p&gt;Prebid Outstream Video Ad&lt;/p&gt;
```

here's my regex to get the change indicators

```swift
 do {
     let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: "@@ (.*) @@", options: .caseInsensitive)
     let matches = regex.matches(in: element, options:[], range: NSRange(location: 0, length: element.utf16.count))

     for match in matches {
         let strElement = element as NSString
         arrMatches.append(strElement.substring(with: match.range) as String)

     }
 } catch {
     print ("Error with regex return")
 }
```

Works as expected, I get all four instances:

```
["@@ -24,7 +24,7 @@", "@@ -33,7 +33,7 @@", "@@ -49,9 +49,9 @@", "@@ -95,9 +95,9 @@"]
```

I now want to capture the changes between the indicators. But I am not getting any results, not even an error on the catch. Here's a hard coded example of what I am trying to do:

```
do {
   let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: "@@ -24,7 +24,7 @@ (.*) @@ -33,7 +33,7 @@", options: .caseInsensitive)
   let matches = regex.matches(in: element, options:[], range: NSRange(location: 0, length: element.utf16.count))
   print(matches.count)//<--prints 0, expecting 1                  
   for match in matches {
      let strElement = element as NSString
      print(":::" + strElement.substring(with: match.range) as String) //<--Nothing prints
   }
 } catch {
      print ("Error with regex return")//<-but nothing prints here either...
 }
```

The content has a lot of tabs and linebreaks so I am wondering if I somehow have to account for those within my regex? Any help would be appreciated.

I should get 4 results, the first result should be:

```
sidebarType: 4

        <div>

-           <div>
+           <div style="width:60vw;">

                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit ....</p>
            </div>
```

the second result would be content between change indicator 2 and 3, the third content between 3 and 4 and the last all content after 4

Comment: If you plan to get some text between the two substrings, `@@ -24,7 +24,7 @@` and `@@ -33,7 +33,7 @@`, use `"(?s)@@ -24,7 \\+24,7 @@(.*)@@ -33,7 \\+33,7 @@"`

Comment: See the edits I added.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - That was it. Thank you. Make it an answer and I'll accept it!

Comment: I posted a dynamic regex solution.

Comment: `"@@ -24,7 \\+24,7 @@([\\S\\s]*?)@@ -33,7 \\+33,7 @@"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
(?s)@@(?:\s+[-+]?\d+(?:,\d+)?){2}\s+@@(.*?)(?=@@(?:\s+[-+]?\d+(?:,\d+)?){2}\s+@@|\z)
```

Get the Group 1 value using `strElement.substring(with: match.range(at: 1)) as String)`.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zYeJ60/1)

See the Swift code demo:

```
let element="3b8d5178f4d21e9269547e8f0bae4b7daa7d8206\nAuthor: Steve <xxxxxx@xxxxxxx.com>\nDate:   Fri Oct 4 16:55:50 2019 -0400\n\n    Fixed responsiveness of code blocks\n\ndiff --git a/examples/video/outstream/pb-ve-outstream-no-server.html b/examples/video/outstream/pb-ve-outstream-no-server.html\nindex ae813578..e18e31ec 100644\n--- a/examples/video/outstream/pb-ve-outstream-no-server.html\n+++ b/examples/video/outstream/pb-ve-outstream-no-server.html\n@@ -24,7 +24,7 @@ sidebarType: 4\n\n        <div>\n\n-           <div>\n+           <div style=\"width:60vw;\">\n\n                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit ....</p>\n            </div>\n@@ -33,7 +33,7 @@ sidebarType: 4\n                <p>Prebid Outstream Video Ad</p>\n             </div>\n\n-           <div>\n+           <div style=\"width:60vw;\">\n                <p>Sed ut perspiciatis ...</p>\n             </div>\n        </div>          \n@@ -49,9 +49,9 @@ sidebarType: 4\n            Do not forget to exchange the placementId in the code examples with your own placementId!</p>\n        </div>\n\n-       <div>\n+       <div style=\"width:60vw;\">\n            <h4>Place this code in the page header.</h4>\n-<pre class=\"pb-code-hl\">\n+<pre class=\"pb-code-hl\" style=\"width:60vw;\">\n <!--put javascript code here-->\n &lt;script&gt;\n     var pbjs = pbjs || {};\n@@ -95,9 +95,9 @@ sidebarType: 4\n        </div>\n\n        <!--body code example-->\n-       <div>\n+       <div style=\"width:60vw;\">\n            <h4>Place this code in the page body.</h4>\n-<pre class=\"pb-code-hl\">\n+<pre class=\"pb-code-hl\" style=\"width:60vw;\">\n <!--put body html and javascript here-->\n &lt;div id='video1'&gt;\n    &lt;p&gt;Prebid Outstream Video Ad&lt;/p&gt;"
do {
   let del = "@@(?:\\s+[-+]?\\d+(?:,\\d+)?){2}\\s+@@"
   let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: "(?s)\(del)(.*?)(?=\(del)|\\z)", options: .caseInsensitive)
   let matches = regex.matches(in: element, options:[], range: NSRange(location: 0, length: element.utf16.count))
   print(matches.count)//<--prints 0, expecting 1                  
   for match in matches {
      let strElement = element as NSString
      print(":::" + strElement.substring(with: match.range(at: 1)) as String) //<--Nothing prints
   }
 } catch {
      print ("Error with regex return")//<-but nothing prints here either...
 }
```

The regex is of the `(?s)\(del)(.*?)(?=\(del)|\z)` form:

- `(?s)` - a DOTALL inline regex modifier
- `\(del)` - the delimiter pattern
- `(.*?)` - Group 1: any 0+ chars, as few as possible
- `(?=\(del)|\z)` - right after, the must be a delimiter pattern or (`|`) end of string (`\z`).

The delimiter pattern matches

- `@@` - a literal string
- `(?:\s+[-+]?\d+(?:,\d+)?){2}` - two occurrences of

  - `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
  - `[-+]?` - an optional `+` or `-`
  - `\d+` - 1+ digits
  - `(?:,\d+)?` - an optional sequence of `,` and 1+ digits
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
- `@@` - a literal string